# Full outer join in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a set of models like this:

```py
class Expense(models.Model):
    debitors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Debitor')
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Debitor(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['person', 'expense']]

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    expense = models.ForeignKey(Expense)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

i.e. I have a many-to-many relationship between `Expense`s and `Person`s *through* `Debitor`s.

For a given `Expense`, I'd like to query all `Debitor`s/`Person`s, **but including `Person`s for which a `Debitor` record does not exist**. In that case, I want a row with a certain `person_id`, but with the `Debitor` and `Expense` columns `null`. In other words, a FULL OUTER JOIN between `Expense`, `Debitor`, and `Person`.

I have not found how to accomplish this with Django's ORM. I have figured out a raw query that does what I want (which is a bit more convoluted because SQLite does not natively support FULL OUTER JOINs):

```sql
SELECT debitor_id as id, amount, src_person.id as person, expense_id as expense
FROM src_person
LEFT JOIN (SELECT src_debitor.id as debitor_id, src_debitor.amount as amount, src_expense.id as expense_id, src_debitor.person_id as person_id
           FROM src_debitor
           INNER JOIN src_expense ON src_debitor.expense_id = src_expense.id and src_expense.id = x) as sol
           ON src_person.id = sol.person_id;
```

For example, for `expense_id=6` this returns:

| id | amount | inhabitant | expense |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| null | null | 3 | null |
| null | null | 4 | null |
| null | null | 5 | null |
| null | null | 6 | null |

However, when executing this query using `Debitor.objects.raw()`, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Debitor.person" must be a "Person" instance.
```

I presume it is not possible to map raw queries to model instances using `Debitor.objects.raw()` when they contain relations to other models? Otherwise I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Is there another/better way to do this? I'm still hoping there is some way to do this within Django's ORM, but I have not found it so far.

Comment: Can you explain *what* you aim to do, not that much *how* you want to do that?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I want an API endpoint that for a given `Expense` yields a list of all `Person`s, with the `Debitor` columns (e.g. `amount`) if a Debitor record exist for that `Expense`.

Comment: I'd try `prefetch_related`/`select_related` since there is a `ManyToManyField`. In case this fails, can't it be solved with two queries?

Comment: @Memristor Two queries would be acceptable. How would I go about doing this with `prefetch_related`/`select_related`, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an sqlite database with the same models you propose, I can get what you want with a raw query using `django.db.connection` and modifying your query, but still not using the Django ORM:

```
from django.db import connection


def my_custom_sql():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
        SELECT debitor.debitor_id, person.id as person_id,
               debitor.amount, expense.expense 
        FROM many2many_person person
        LEFT JOIN (
          select debitor.id as debitor_id, debitor.amount as amount,
                 debitor.person_id as person_id, debitor.expense_id
          from many2many_debitor debitor
          where debitor.expense_id=1 -- your x here
        ) debitor on debitor.person_id=person.id
        LEFT JOIN (
          select expense.id, expense.total_amount as expense
          from many2many_expense expense
          where id=1                 -- your x here
        ) expense on expense.id=debitor.expense_id
        """)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

    print(rows)

    return rows
```

In my case this returns (I have 5 `Person` only one with `Expense`):

```
[
  (1, 1, 10, 100),
  (None, 2, None, None),
  (None, 3, None, None),
  (None, 4, None, None),
  (None, 5, None, None)
]
```

Meaning all the `Person` objects are there but only those with `expense_id=1`  have the rest of data filled. In your case you have to change the `many2many_` for `src_`.

I have tried with Django `OuterRef` and `Subquery` but failed completly.

**Another attempt**: modifying the answer of @WillemVanOnsem (this attemp returns as many `Debitor` for each `Person` so not what OP wants):

```
expense_id = 1
persons = Person.objects.annotate(
        debitor_id=Case(
            When(debitor__expense_id=expense_id, then=F('debitor__id')),
            default=Value(None),
        ),
        amount=Case(
            When(debitor__expense_id=expense_id, then=F('debitor__amount')),
            default=Value(None),
        ),
        expense_id=Case(
            When(debitor__expense_id=expense_id, then=F('debitor__expense_id')),
            default=Value(None),
        )
    ).distinct()
```

this gives me the same output that my modified query.

**Third attempt**: I use `OuterRef` and `Subquery` to retrieve information for each value associated with a given `expense_id`:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

expense_id = 1

debitor_id_subquery = Debitor.objects.filter(
  person_id=OuterRef('pk'), expense_id=expense_id
).values('id')[:1]
amount_subquery = Debitor.objects.filter(
  person_id=OuterRef('pk'), expense_id=expense_id
).values('amount')[:1]
expense_id_subquery = Debitor.objects.filter(
  person_id=OuterRef('pk'),
  expense_id=expense_id
).values('expense_id')[:1]

persons = Person.objects.annotate(
  debitor_id=Subquery(debitor_id_subquery),
  amount=Subquery(amount_subquery),
  expense_id=Subquery(expense_id_subquery)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first raw query is equivalent to the query I posted in my question, right? I presume it works with `connection.cursor()` instead of `Debitor.objects.raw()`, but in the end I do want to map this result to a list of `Debitor` objects.

Comment: The approach using `annotate()` does not seem to work correctly either. It returns multiple rows per `Person`, including for different `Expense`s than the one specified, like @WillemVanOnsem's answer.

Comment: @Compizfox there goes my third, and last, attempt. I've checked the results and created more entries in my database, even checked for non existence expenses.

Answer (score 1):

> I want an API endpoint that for a given Expense yields a list of all Persons, with the `Debitor` columns (e.g. amount) if a `Debitor` record exist for that Expense.

I think you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import F

Person.objects.annotate(
    amount=F('debitor__amount')
).filter(debitor__expense__pk=expense_pk)
```

this will retrieve the `Person`s related to the `Expense` with as primary key *`expense_pk`*. The `Person`s from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.amount` which is the amount for that `debitor` is.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this does not seem to work correctly. I'm not sure what it is doing, but it returning multiple items per `Person` (and for different expenses than the one specified by the filter), for only two `Persons` in the system.

Comment: @Compizfox: is the same person for the same expense part through multiple `Debitor`s?

Comment: @Compizfox: can you provide some sample data of your models and the query that renders the wrong result?

Comment: No, `Person` and `Expense` are `unique_together` on `Debitor` so there is only (or no) `Debitor` per `Person`/`Expense` pair.

Comment: I'll have to check how to best give that (it won't fit in a comment)...

Comment: @Compizfox: you can edit the question with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

While I could not find a way to do this completely in SQL (either using a raw query or with Django's ORM), I solved it by writing this method for `Expense`:

```py
    def get_debitors(self):
        """
        Get a list of Debitors for each Person, including those for which a Debitor entry does not exist (i.e.
        outer join)
        """

        debitors = []
        for person in Person.objects.prefetch_related('debitor_set__expense').all():
            try:
                debitors.append(person.debitor_set.get(expense=self))
            except Debitor.DoesNotExist:
                debitors.append(Debitor(person=person, amount=None))

        return debitors
```

It does the construction of the list in Python rather than in SQL, but using `prefetch_related()` it should only cost one query, so I suppose this is good enough.